# Powershell condition to send mail

Tags: powershell

I want to create a scheduled task that will do the following :

1. Check if the files are xlsx type, then check if they are from today
2. Count rows in the excel files that are in the first condition
3. Send mail depending on the following conditions:

   - if there are no files today - send mail no files for today
   - if there are files today but less than 2 rows - files are copied but no data
   - if there are files today and more than 2 rows - files are copied.

I have the code but I doesn't do all the conditions above.
I don't have any errors but it seems that it doesn't do what is supposed to.

I have 2 xls files there that are read and found but I have 5 and 6 rows so basically it should send me just the message that the files were copied, it keeps sending the files are copied but no data, which should be the condition if I have less than two rows.

I have tried a lot of things, nothing seems to be working - couldn't post all the trials and way I thought. Any ideas on how to rewrite or edit this script?

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.application
$directory = get-childitem -path "\*.xlsx" 
$ExcelFiles = $directory | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -gt $limit }  | ForEach{
    $WB = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($_.fullname)
    Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'RowCount' -NotePropertyValue ($Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) -PassThru
    $WB.Close()
}
$Excel.Quit()
$Final = $ExcelFiles | Format-Table Name,RowCount -AutoSize | Out-String


If($Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count -lt 2) {



$smtpServer = "domain.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "domain@domain.com"
$msg.To.Add("domain@domain.com")
$msg.Subject = "xxxxxxxxxx"
$msg.Body ="files copied but not enough rows "
#$msg.Body +=
$msg.Body +="$Final"
$smtp.Send($msg)

}else{ 
If($ExcelFiles.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count -gt 3) {


$smtpServer = "domain.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "domain@domain.com"
$msg.To.Add("domain@domain.com")
$msg.Subject = "xxxxxxxxxx "
$msg.Body ="files copied "
#$msg.Body +=
$msg.Body +="$Final"
$smtp.Send($msg)


}}

If($ExcelFiles.Count -eq 0) {

$smtpServer = "domain@domain.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "domain@domain.com"
$msg.To.Add("domain@domain.com")
$msg.Subject = "xxxxxxxxx "
$msg.Body ="Files not copied!"
$smtp.Send($msg)

}
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you (actually) using? You've tagged it [tag:powershell-2.0], but you're using language features in your script that didn't exist until 3.0

Comment: latest version of powershell. its going to run on a windows server 2019 standard edition

Comment: You cannot test on `$Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count` **after** you closed the workbook and Excel itself. Test for files like `$ExcelFiles | Where-Object { $_.RowCount -lt 2}`. (RowCount is the property you have added to each FileInfo object after all)

Comment: @Theo the changes I made , where you did offer the input worked. the only issue is now i keep getting the message that the file is in use ( most likely instace remained open ) and I can not access the files via explorer what should I need to add to the function so it closes everything after it is done?

Comment: Please see my answer. Because your code only uses `$Excel.Quit()`, and does not dispose of the com objects, it may take a long time for the system to clean up (garbage collection), leaving the files 'in use' until that finally happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it like this:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.application
$directory = Get-ChildItem -path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.xlsx' -File

$ExcelFiles = $directory | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $limit }  | ForEach-Object {
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
    # output just a subset of properties you're interested in as PSCustomObject
    $_ | Select-Object Name, @{Name = 'RowCount'; Expression = {$Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count}}
    $wb.Close()
}
$Excel.Quit()
# important, clean-up COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# capture a table-formatted string to use as body text.
# this will only display 'nice' if wrapped in HTML `<pre>..</pre>` tags,
# so it is displayed in a monospaced font.
$body = "<pre>`r`n{0}`r`n</pre>" -f ($ExcelFiles | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Trim()

if (@($ExcelFiles).Count -eq 0) {
    $subject = 'No Files copied'
    $body    = 'Files were NOT copied!'
}
else {
    # get the number of files that don't have enough rows
    $badFiles = @($ExcelFiles | Where-Object { $_.RowCount -lt 2 }).Count
    if ($badFiles) {
        $subject = "Files were copied, but $badFiles without enough rows.."
    }
    else {
        $subject = 'All files copied OK'
    }
}

# next, send the email. This example uses the Send-MailMessage cmdlet
# using Splatting for the parameters
$mailParams = @{
    To         = "domain@domain.com"
    From       = "domain@domain.com"
    Subject    = $subject
    Body       = $body
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    SmtpServer = "smtp.domain.com"
    # add more parameters here when needed
}

Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Comment: Thank you, made the changes as per the need and it works perfectly. there are some things there that I will dissect such as the system.runtime and system.gc , but aside that straight forward and clean. thank you a lot. marked as the answer and voted.